# What does it take to damage an internally geared hub?

Tags: maintenance, internally-geared-hub, damage

What behavior can easily damage an internally geared hub (Shimano Nexus or Alfine for example)?

- can one jump off high (say 50cm) curbs?
- can it be damaged by shifting gears under too much torque?
- does water get in if it gets briefly submerged?
- are there any dos and donts, any habits one has to change after using derailleurs?

**Edit/followup question:** are hubs with fewer gears more durable in general?

Comment: People do go mountain biking with Rohloff hubs, though there is a huge difference in prince and quality between those and your bottom of the line SRAM/Shimano/Sturmy-Archer/etc. hub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually jumping curbs isn't a problem, as long as you're cognizant of not landing incredibly hard.  I would think that rough landings would damage the rim before the hub.

Most internal hubs wouldn't shift under torque at all.  Some have a system where they won't even try to shift if the mechanism is moving, others have a "sprung" system where it waits for a pause in pedaling and makes the shift then.

Brief submersion shouldn't be a problem.  Prolonged would most likely cause big problems.  I don't know if shifting while submerged would exacerbate this...

The biggest factor I've seen in damage to an internal hub is using one that's slightly mis-tuned for a long time.  I'll have someone come in saying that it stopped shifting into third about a year ago, and now it won't shift into second...  By the time they bring it in to the shop, now it's a much bigger problem than it would have been a year ago.

Comment: I have seen in the [nexus SG-8R36 documentation (**NOTE:** section)](http://bike.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Nexus/InternalHub/SG8R31_36/37J0A-001_SG-8R31_36-EN_v1_m56577569830638076.pdf) that you can shift gears while pedaling. I guess I will just go and test an actual bike.

Comment: Lack of oil, or failure to do the oil changes as required would also contribute to accelerated failure.

Comment: With regard to wheel damage, the fact that an internal-gear hub is likely larger diameter than its derailleur counterpart means that the spokes are shorter and likely approach the rim at a sharper angle.  This results in more stress on the spokes and an increased probability of spoke breakage.

Comment: @Criggie OK, even with derailleurs its not advised AFAIK so I pause anyway. I was just trying to figure out if it is more dangerous for hubs. Also some people told me that wheelies are bad. Is it true?

Comment: @ivan you can shift gears while pedalling gently. High chain/pedal pressure holds the gears in place despite the shifter's position, and drastically increases internal wear. And it makes a lame "clank-clank" noise on the IGH I've tried. You need to back off pedal pressure for half a second or so to let the shift through.   Wheelies would be no worse than any other bike.  Jumps and impacts, the load is carried by the axles, so the only relevant effect is that the IGH weighs a bit more, so therefore the bike is slightly heavier.

Comment: @Criggie yeah, 1.6 kilos for 8 speed ones sound heavy, but weight of all those components in the front is also gone.